# Mask xml tags value using regex

Tags: java, regex

Input -

```
String s = "<Name1>Edward Smith</Name1>";
```

Tried following things to mask values within using

```
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("<Name1>(.{5})(?:.+?)</Name1>", "<Name1>*****$1</Name1>"));
```

But above code masks as following

```
<Name1>*****Edwar</Name1>
```

Expected Output:

```
<Name1>*****d Smith</Name1>
```

Just want to mask first five characters and remaining string should be as is.

For less than or equal to five chars the output should be Number of chars masked..

```
<Name1>*****</Name1>
```

Any help will be appreciated, Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```java
   System.out.println(s.replaceAll("<Name1>(.{1,5})(.*)</Name1>", "<Name1>*****$2</Name1>"));
```

More explanation [here](https://regex101.com/r/BaKlFf/1)

**Edit**  here is code to track count of masked characters:

```java
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class RegexXmlRplc {
    private static Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<Name1>(.{1,5})(.*)</Name1>");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "<Name1>joe</Name1>";
        mask(s);
        s = "<Name1>Edward Smith</Name1>";
        mask(s);

    }

    private static void mask(String s) {
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
        if (matcher.find()) {
            int length = matcher.group(1).length();
            String replacement = "<Name1>" + "*".repeat(length) + "$2</Name1>";
            System.out.println(matcher.replaceAll(replacement));
        } else {
            System.out.println("No match");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply,It works..But for names less than 5 chars stars should be number of chars..For Example <Name1>Joe</Name1> -- > <Name1>***</Name1>

Comment: I have added code according to your request. Can you check it?

Comment: Wanted to handle in Regex itself..